# How to subset columns by factor in a row?

Tags: r

```
x <- c("a", 2, 3, 1.0)
y <- c("b", 1, 6, 7.9)
z <- c("c", 1, 8, 2.0)
p <- c("d", 2, 9, 3.3)

df1 <- data.frame(x,y,z,p)
```

Here is a quick example data set, but it doesn't mirror exactly what im trying to do.  Say I wanted to take 50 random samples from each level of factor in row 2 (in this case we only have 2 levels of the factor)... How would I go about coding that efficiently?  I have a version working in a loop but it feels needlessly complex

edit:  When I say I want to take 50 random samples I mean take 50 columns from each level of the factor.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but this is very difficult to understand.

Comment: @RichardScriven It's not just you.

Comment: So in row 2 of this data frame we have the factor 1 and 2.  I would like to take 50 random columns containing a 1 in row 2 and also 50 random columns containing a 2 in row 2.  I would like those to be in the same dataframe when finished - not like the result of the split function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to extract a factor (assuming that 2nd row is a factor).

```
fact <- as.factor(as.matrix(df1[2,]))
```

And then work with the second column which you want to be a factor. For example, to sample all for the first value of factor

```
df1[,df1[2,]==levels(fact)[1],]
```

Or for getting exactly 50:

```
df1[,df1[2,]==levels(fact)[1],][1:50]
```

Comment: The way the code runs I would be transposing the data frame a few thousand times.  Probably not the best way to do it, in this case.

Comment: That's true, but that's the only way I can think of in case you don't know, what columns will correspond to a factor. Because the accepted answer is based on the predefined indexes of columns to sample and this way if more generic

Comment: OK, it looks like ill have to write code to identify which columns to sample for each level.

Comment: @user2795569, I got more elegant solution now without need transpose

Comment: very nice!  its similar in logic to the loop i have already, but so much cleaner and shorter

Comment: I ended up going with something looking like this                                    for (i in 1:20){
df1_sampler <- cbind(badloopcode,sample(df1[,df1[2,]==levels(fact)[i]],size=samplenumber,replace=F))}                                                  it removed many lines from my previous code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking to do something like this:

```
x1 <- df1[,sample(c(1,4),50,replace = TRUE)]
x2 <- df1[,sample(c(2,3),50,replace = TRUE)]
```

...but your question is very confusing. "factor" refers to something very specific in R: a type of variable that is generally stored in a column of a data frame, never a row. Additionally, you appear to be forcing all your columns themselves to be factors (or characters possibly), which seems an odd way to store the value `3.3`.

Comment: That does what im looking for.  I actually never use R enough to retain much useful information between uses.  Can you explain what the c(1,4) and c(2,3) parts of the code are doing?  Is there I way to make this run over 20 levels of the values in row 2?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  You are specifying which columns to sample.  I need to do that logically not manually.. if you know what I mean.